# could someone tell me why this file has a empty space at the begininng?

Tags: file, go

I have this file https://storage.googleapis.com/johnbalvin/test/test.txt

when I open it on notepad or any editor, it doesn't show any blank space, however when getting it's content through code, it shows an empy space at the beginning.

I would like to know why is this the case

I know this is not a programming in general but rather the file itself, but I'm not sure where to put it

Could some help me please.

Thanks[image]

Comment: What do you get if you do: `fmt.Printf("%c", contentRaw1[0])`?

Comment: this symbol => ï

Comment: Then Sergio's answer is accurate.

Comment: but shouldn't the symbol show on editor?

Comment: It's up to the editor to decide how it will render what byte. Some editors show these BOMs, some don't. Some editors show special symbols even for new lines, most don't.

Comment: With vim on mac I get this: https://i.imgur.com/Gy63hW8.png

Comment: oh, the charecter get's shown on vim, it's interesting. Im not sure how that character got there, I just created a file on a windows machine by remote access and after some debugging on my real code, I found this was the issue

Comment: Windows programs (including PowerShell) are notorious for inserting unnecessary utf8 BOMs. It's good to keep an eye out for these and remove them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first three bytes of this file are 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF. That's the byte order mark for UTF-8: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: ok but what does that mean? if the first item is an empty space, then shouldn't show on editor?

Comment: it's not an empty space. When these three bytes start a file, it means that the following bytes should be interpreted as UTF-8. Why it's resulting in printing an empty space in your program, I don't yet know. Might have something to do with you reading the file and printing it as a stream of bytes instead of a string.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article: `If the BOM character appears in the middle of a data stream, Unicode says it should be interpreted as a "zero-width non-breaking space"`.  Since your terminal window uses a monospaced font, a "zero-width" character doesn't make sense. So perhaps the compromise is to display it as a full-width space, rather than omitting it entirely.